# Sorting by multiple columns where each column is in different order

Tags: python

To sort a tuple list using two columns I do:

```
t_l = sorted(t_l, key = lambda t_l: (t_l[-1], t_l[1]))
```

How can I sort such that t_l[-1] is in ascending order, which is the default, but t_l[1] is sorted in descending order?

Using reverse = True would sort both columns in descending order.

Any ideas?

Comment: If one of columns is numbers then you can use `-t_l[1]` as it's key.

Comment: Are either of the columns numeric?

Comment: Thanks zch. That is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the sort of one of the columns if either of the columns is numeric, or can be expressed as numbers as well. You can then simply *negate* the numeric column to reverse the sort for that column.

If the `t_l[-1]` column is numeric, use:

```
sorted(t_l, key=lambda i: (-i[-1], i[1]))
```

(using different names for the input list and the `lambda` argument reduces confusion)

If that column is not numeric but the other one is, you can still use the same trick, but need to reverse the whole sort:

```
sorted(t_l, key=lambda i: (i[-1], -i[1]), reverse=True)
```

Single-character columns can be made numeric by using the `ord()` function; using `ord()` will result in the same sorting order, but since it is numeric you can now reverse it:

```
sorted(t_l, key=lambda i: (-ord(i[-1]), i[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out a simple solution on an example

```
t_l = [[3,4,5,6,2,4,6],[6,7,3,4,5]]

t_l = [sorted(t_l[0], reverse = False),sorted(t_l[1], reverse = True)]
```

gives

```
>>> t_l
[[2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6], [7, 6, 5, 4, 3]]
```

is it what you look for?